# What is better async style in these two Node.js examples?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am working through nodeschool.io learnyounode and on the fourth challenge, which is:

> Write a program that uses a single asynchronous filesystem operation to read a file and print the number of newlines it contains to the console (stdout), similar to running cat file | wc -l.

I wrote one solution, which is different than the solution provided, but both seem to work, and I am curious to know which would be better style, and how they might function differently.

Here is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileAsArray = [];

function asyncRead(print) {
  fs.readFile(process.argv[2], 'utf-8', function callback(error, contents) {
    fileAsArray = contents.split('\n');
    print();
  })
}

function printNumberOfLines() {
  console.log(fileAsArray.length - 1);
}

asyncRead(printNumberOfLines);
```

And here is the solution provided by learnyounode:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = process.argv[2]

fs.readFile(file, function (err, contents) {
  // fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', callback) can also be used
  var lines = contents.toString().split('\n').length - 1
  console.log(lines)
})
```

I also noticed that the learnyounode code lacks semicolons. I thought they were strongly recommended/required?

Comment: Why are you putting the result into a global variable in the first block of code?  That seems quite undesirable.  You should just pass the data to your callback and not use a global.

Comment: @jfriend00 Great point! I was using [this](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) as a reference, where it uses a global variable.

Comment: And, that example explicitly shows why using a global is dangerous.  In general, globals are to be avoided, but they are specifically to be avoided in asynchronous code because async results can only be safely used in the scope in which they are produced and putting those results into a global invites misuse and all sorts of timing related bugs.